# I am trying hard to identify Python pandas error in code

Tags: python, pandas

A code i am trying to develop to give forcast, taking input from various source.

the reason i have pasted the code for easier understand.

i am getting below error. May someone please please help me if i missed something. what i should change to fix the issue.
**i am sure cognos_cols is a list*

I am trying to find out whether it is a problem with code or Input Data, Please share your thoughts.

Many Thanks

Comment: it's hard to debug large blocks of code all hidden in a function, why don't you try breaking your code into small chunks that you can debug?

Comment: It's a bit difficult to debug given the formatting and how much code you've shared, but for the first TypeError, I believe that Pandas pivot_tables require a list or list-like input for columns and index. If you only want on column, make it `[DataType]`. Otherwise, please edit your question to make it more legible and edit the title please.

Comment: @GabeRon: Thanks Gabe...... I  will check again.......

Comment: @GabeRon: As You Suggest, i have tried to copy full code for 1 segment.... Kindly share your thoughts.

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base on this part of the code where the variable names appear, and your error, are you sure that `cognos_cols` is a list?

```
cognos_cols = 'DataType,Combi,Month,Year,Qty_Val'.split(',')

df_cis = pd.read_csv(cis_file, sep=None, encoding = "UTF-16", 
                        header=None, engine='python', names = cognos_cols, usecols=[0, 1, 3, 4, 5])
df_volume =  pd.read_csv(volume_file, sep=None, encoding = "UTF-16", 
                        header=None, engine='python', names = cognos_cols, usecols=[0, 1, 3, 4, 5])
df_ryo_pop = pd.read_excel(lookups_xls, 'RYOPOP', header=0)
df_am = pd.read_excel(lookups_xls, 'AM_names', header=0).drop_duplicates('AM Code')
```

Comment: Many Thanks Alfonso..... i will accept as answer...... please give me some time to re-verify.

Comment: also if that's the error I would write `cognos_cols` on a more pythonic way like:

cognos_cols = ['DataType', 'Combi', 'Month', 'Year', 'Qty_Val']

Comment: Thank You Very Much Alfonso, I have edited with little more on the code, please share your thoughts if that makes sense.

Comment: i am sure cognos_cols is a list.